# In Prolog, how do I turn all answers to a query into a list?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm just starting with Prolog.

And with using web-server functionality.

I want to have a page which is a list of all things in the db that meet a certain predicate.

How do I turn the query of a predicate into a list?

Or if there's a danger of an infinite number of results, how do I do the equivalent of a "take n"?

Comment: To find all the answers, use `findall/3`. SWI has an extension called [`findnsols/4`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findnsols/4) which will get you just the first ten or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog proposes a peculiar HTML generation utility, DCG based. Then you can be interested in library([dcg/high_order](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=highorder)), possibly to be mixed with library([solution_sequences](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)), where you find predicates apt to reduce the SQL 'impedence mismatch' experienced when approaching SWI-Prolog fom other - more common - developing experiences.

Let's try to adapt [this documentation sample](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=html-write-examples) for library([http/html_write](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=htmlwrite)), refactoring apropos_rows//1 into apropos_row//1, that performs the truly required formatting, and a call to sequence//2:

```
apropos_page(Kwd, Matches) -->
        page([ title(['Predicates for ', Kwd])
             ],
             [ h2(align(center),
                  ['Predicates for ', Kwd]),
               table([ align(center),
                       border(1),
                       width('80%')
                     ],
                     [ tr([ th('Predicate'),
                            th('Summary')
                          ])
                     | \sequence(apropos_row, Matches)
                     ])
             ]).

apropos_row(pred(Name, Arity, Summary)) -->
        html([ tr([ td(\predref(Name/Arity)),
                    td(em(Summary))
                  ])
             ]).
```